# Create children of datalist by using Virtualize

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I am trying to create children of datalist tag by using Virtualize to avoid creating of all items in one time but i didn't work, my code:

```
<div class="form-group row">
<label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label" for="organizationInput">Organisatie: </label>
<input type="text" class=" col-sm-4 form-control" id="organizationInput" list="organizationlist" @onchange="@((args) => Name= args.Value.ToString())" />
<datalist class="col-auto" id="organizationlist">
    <Virtualize Items="Organizations" Context="item">

        <ItemContent>

            <option @key="item.REL_Nummer">@item.REL_Naam01</option>

        </ItemContent>

    </Virtualize>
</datalist>
@if (SelectedOrganization != null)
{
    <label class="col-auto col-form-label">@($"Organization Name: {SelectedOrganization.REL_Naam01}")</label>
}
```

Please If you have an advise or I have a wrong, correct me!.

Answer (score 0):

There is right now an [open issue in Github](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/29123) and the blazor-virtualization doesn't support select or datalist as a container, this issue will be moved to next sprint planning.